# use local xml file for a twilio call

Tags: c#, .net-core, twilio, telephony

The [sample code on how-to-make-a-call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-csharp) looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
    const string accountSid = "ACc610c3a41a31c91a01396f7bf92c517d";
    const string authToken = "your_auth_token";
    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

    var to = new PhoneNumber("+14155551212");
    var from = new PhoneNumber("+15017122661");
    var call = CallResource.Create(to,
                                   from,
                                   url: new Uri("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"));

Console.WriteLine(call.Sid);
}
```

The xml of the referenced voice.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">Thanks for trying our documentation. Enjoy!</Say>
    <Play>http://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

I would like to just create an xml file in memory, and reference that, rather than a remote uri. Is there anyway to take something like the below and attach it to the CallResource.Create argument?

```
    System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    String s = "My custom message!";
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(string.Format(@"<Response><Say voice=""alice"">{0}</Say></Response>", s));
```

Comment: Just a quick question why are you using XmlDocument?
If there is no good reason you should definitely look into XDocument (System.Xml.Linq)

Comment: @C1rdec no particular reason, I'll optimize once I get the thing running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently there is no way to send the [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/) for a call with the request to create the call. You do need the TwiML to be hosted somewhere.

If it would be difficult for you to host TwiML, then you could look into [TwiML Bins](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/twiml-bins) or [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) for static and dynamic ways of hosting TwiML within Twilio.

Comment: Phil, does the URL need to be publicly accessible or only via running application?

Comment: It needs to be accessible by Twilio from the Internet. You can [validate that requests come from Twilio and protect it with HTTP basic auth](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security) to ensure that only Twilio can access it though.

Comment: I "solved" this by presenting the xml via an mvc service that produces xml, and I reference that controller/action/id to twilio. Still a pain to work with a non-publicly accessible development instance.

Answer (score 1):

Well its funny Before I have asked a similar question and now I'm answering it. Try this:
I created an method that takes a string message as parameter which is the message I want to  over the call. I call this method before execution of the create call and I put a break, and found that the xml was created in the correct format in the specified directory.`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>`enter code here
  `<Say>HELLO WORLD</Say>
</Response>`
Line 43 I created the method. Then in line 70 I called the method the Xml file was created like below:

`enter code here`
  HELLO WORLD

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K96PT.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you actually can send it from you local xml file:

```
    client.calls
    .create({
        twiml: '<Response><Say>### THIS STRING CAN BE REPLACED WITH YOUR XML FILE CONTENT ###</Say></Response>',
        from: '',
        to: ''
    })
    .then(call => console.log(message.sid));
```